# NuGet restore packages crashes when two parallel threads attempt to restore same package

Tags: jenkins, nuget, nuget-package-restore, cakebuild

I have a build where multiple parallel stages each start out with a NuGet restore, before doing different stuff (build and run tests, build for iOS, build for Android). The restore is executed in each stage, since they can run on different build agents. However, since our CI setup has two executors per agent, they can also end up being executed on the same agent, and this is where my issue occurs.

When NuGet comes across a package that is not in the global packages directory (~/.nuget/packages, since I'm building on Macs), it will attempt to install it, and this tends to happen concurrently in the two parallel stages, causing an error to occur in either or both stages. The error message will be along the lines of:

```
[Stage1] Installing BtDriver 1.0.0. 
[Stage1] WARNING: Error downloading 'BtDriver.1.0.0' from 'https://MyArtifactory/api/nuget/BtDriver/1.0.0'.
[Stage1] Directory /Users/MyUser/.nuget/packages/btdriver/1.0.0/lib is not empty
```

Or from the other stage:

```
[Stage2] Installing BtDriver 1.0.0.
[Stage2] WARNING: Error downloading 'BtDriver.1.0.0' from 'https://MyArtifactory/api/nuget/BtDriver/1.0.0'.
[Stage2] /Users/MyUser/.nuget/packages/btdriver/1.0.0/g45y07q7.6ap does not exist
```

I have looked far and wide for a solution to this, but so far I have been unable to find anyone running into the same issue, leading me to believe, that I may have missed something obvious, so I hope someone can lead me in the right direction.

Bonus info: I'm using Jenkins to assign the agents and orchestrate the build and NuGet Restore is invoked using Cake's [NuGetRestore()](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.NuGet/NuGetAliases/E6B1300E) method, but I'm able to reproduce using only 'nuget restore' from two separate terminals at the same time, so I'm assuming the error does not lie with Jenkins or Cake, although solutions involving either will be welcome.

I have considered adding a small delay to one of the stages, so there is a smaller chance of the two restores executing concurrently, but I would prefer a more robust solution. Limiting the number of executors to one per agent is not feasible either.

Comment: Why don't you restore the packages then build them. It'd help if you shared how your building these components

Comment: @liam: I need to restore directly before the build, because the three stages might be executed on three different agents. I didn't add the build info, since the error occurs before the build even starts, but I can add some more info if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

We have many CI agents running on the same hosts.
We eventually get rid of this problem with a custom MSBuildWithMutex task.
https://gist.github.com/dedale/675ec80313f2a70266deb0ab78a0e2c6

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've had partial success telling nuget/msbuild to use different paths for its caches.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders for environment variables.

However, once past that issue I sometimes see socket errors with nuget restores running in parallel. I believe that each nuget process is fighting for access to the remote server and causing timeouts.

I am looking for a clean approach - perhaps convincing Jenkins to use a different home directory for each executor, so that I don't have to run extra code in each job, but I haven't figured out how to do that yet.